# For restfulness, should I use one method for different get requests or seperate them

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I am making a Blackjack rest service, and currently have 4 GET endpoints:

```
/hit
/stand
/double down
/surrender
```

I could also make just 1 POST/PATCH endpoint that uses a dto to send a move, or should I keep
using these four uri's?

Which option would be more restful/better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Resources are nouns; in this case, the resource is a game, or a hand within the game. These are not resources (URLs), they're state changes that go along with a single mutation (POST) endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one endpoint. All of these actions/commands are working with the same set of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a single REST endpoint that takes a RequestBody and returns  links as part of the response.

- When links are returned as part of response, we are implementing HATEOS which increases the RESTfulness of the API. (reaches Level 3 of Richardson's Maturity Model)
- Client can understand the links received as part of the response and can take next step of actions accordingly. This prevents the client from having to make multiple REST calls just to accomplish one task as a whole.
- (Personal Development experience) If we maintain too many REST APIs, especially GET APIs, code maintenance increases overtime. Also, it is not extensible in nature, i.e. if a new requirement comes up and we do not have a DTO then we have to define multiple new endpoints. On the other hand, if we have a less number of endpoints with a DTO, we have the flexibility to enhance the DTO itself to have attributes that can help us achieve the new functionality.

For further reading, [this](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/rest-architecture) is a good article on REST.